# Is there a word for happiness made possible by a tragic situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I frequently find myself needing a word to express happiness that acknowledges a tragic or unfortunate circumstance underpinning that happiness. Preferably the word could have both adjective and verb forms. For example, "Gregory *[**verb**-ed | felt **adjective** about]* the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change."

"Bittersweet" is close, but not precisely right. It implies ambivalence rather than genuine gladness. "Schadenfreude" is also in the neighborhood, but I don't want to imply that the tragic part of the situation is what *causes* the pleasure. (Also, I recognize that the word may not quite exist in English, and I don't know if this is forbidden for this forum, but I'd welcome a loan word or phrase if there's a better one.)

Comment: Phrase / saying, fine; purely foreign word, totally off-topic.

Comment: Schadenfreude and the English equivalent: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378283/will-the-word-schadenfreude-be-understood-in-an-english-text/378284#378284, I'm just not sure it works in this situation (as you note).

Comment: Is the implication that Gregory doesn't care or feel sad about the prospect of climate change? If not, it's unclear to me how bittersweet doesn't fit.

Comment: I think someone could feel both *glad and perplexed* by a balmy February day. Consider using two adjectives. "Gregory felt both glad and perplexed at this balmy February day." You could also try a phrase. "Gregory felt reluctant happiness at this balmy February day."

Comment: "Gregory felt 'solace' in the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change." Solace is that feeling you get when you are distressed yet consoled in a situation.

Comment: Gregory felt **ambivalent**... I don't have the reputation to provide an answer.

Comment: Does "heaven" work?

Comment: "Ill-gotten gain" is the phrase I've heard most often for this kind of thing. It refers to any benefits achieved by way of misfortune. The balmy February day is the ill-gotten gain in this case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "I'd welcome a foreign **loan** word..."

Comment: @Kyle Strand From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loanword): **loanword**: a word of one language taken into another **and naturalized** (bolding mine). A foreign loanword must be say a Spanish word adopted into Italian. Off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ...right. So, if OP is using the phrase "loan word" correctly, then it is *on* topic, since loanwords *are* part of English.

Comment: Though I suppose it's explicitly marked as potentially off-topic, so perhaps OP means a word that has *not* yet been naturalized, in which case I can see that your clarification is entirely appropriate.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower I assume that's a joke, but I don't get it....

Comment: @KyleStrand In Edwin´s defense, he wrote that before I edited to add "loan" in a feeble attempt to keep it on-topic.

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks for pointing that out; I hadn't noticed the edit history.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate (and certainly containing just about all these answers): [Is there an expression that means something bad as a precursor to something good?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167007/is-there-an-expression-that-means-something-bad-as-a-precursor-to-something-good/167013#167013).

Comment: "Bittersweet" implies both gladness _and_ sadness, which I think perfectly fits your example sentence. For that matter, "ambivalent" can also describe a state of mind in which genuine gladness is accompanied by painful thoughts. Words that could _not_ be used in the sense you want are "lukewarm" and "indifferent," which would imply that Gregory's desire for a balmy day and fear of catastrophic climate change prevent him from being either happy or sad about the combined outcome.

Comment: Aristotle's 'catharsis'? Matches your title if not your examples.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about an *alloyed pleasure*, or maybe a *tarnished pleasure*.

An **unalloyed pleasure** is a pleasure with no drawbacks, no downsides.

In this instance, we have a pleasure (in the sunny day) that was alloyed (or tarnished) by the realisation that the unseasonable warmth was caused by climate change.

> "Gregory felt a *tarnished pleasure* in the balmy February day,
>   suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and
>   irreversible climate change."
>
> "Gregory felt an *alloyed pleasure* in the balmy February day,
>   suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and
>   irreversible climate change."
>
> "Gregory's *pleasure* in the balmy February day was *tarnished* by his
>   suspicion that it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and
>   irreversible climate change."
>
> "Gregory's *pleasure* in the balmy February day was *alloyed* by his
>   suspicion that it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and
>   irreversible climate change."

Comment: 'Guilty pleasure' would be more idiomatic.

Comment: This is my favorite response! "Guilty pleasure" is also close, but understates the guilt. Precisely because it's idiomatic, it now connotes more mild embarrassment than significant sorrow. "Alloyed (or tarnished) pleasure" is stronger, and very evocative, I think.

Comment: I hope you haven't trademarked "tarnished pleasure" yet.  That's wonderfully evocative, and I plan on using it soon.  But I'm afraid "alloyed pleasure" doesn't sing at all.

Comment: Yes, I prefer "tarnished" to "alloyed". No trademark applied - have at it!

Comment: I prefer alloyed, tarnished to me has more of a suggestion that it's _become_ worse. I'd say 'took' rather than 'felt an' though: remove the adjective and you wouldn't write 'Gregory felt a pleasure in...'

Comment: I looked up 'alloyed', and found this is a thing, but I for one have never heard this word used like this and would not have been sure what you meant.

Comment: Both 'tarnished pleasure' and 'alloyed pleasure' have been used before, so you are not coining either phrase. But please bear in mind nohat's comment on a previous thread: ''I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word [/phrase]  invented. While I delight in exciting new words being invented and promulgated, I think we will rapidly lose our reputation as a place where people can get authoritative answers if many answers are not authoritative but just merely inventive."

Comment: That makes sense but if the poster has indicated that it's a coinage, then that ought to be OK? Anyway, if I didn't coin it, I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 55):

Possibly a **"silver lining?"**

> a sign of hope in an unfortunate or gloomy situation; a bright prospect

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/silver-lining)

It has a meaning of being a positive thing coming out of a negative event

Comment: > I'm sorry that your business  failed and went into bankruptcy but every cloud has a Silver Lining.

Comment: close, but in this instance, Gregory was enjoying the sunny weather until he had the thought that it was probably caused by climate change.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow It can work if you invert the sentence, like: "Climate change is terrible for the planet, but there is a **silver lining**: look at the great weather we're having this week! This time of year, five years ago, I would still be carrying my umbrella everywhere!"

Comment: Yes, but the sequence of emotions in a "silver lining" situation is sadness at the bad aspect of the situation, mitigated by happiness at the one good thing to come out of it. The sequence of emotions in this situation is happiness at the good weather, followed by sadness that its probably cause is climate change. It is similar, but it is not the same.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow "Gregory was enjoying the sunny weather until he had the thought that it was probably caused by climate change" That is the opposite of silver lining. Silver lining implies optimism and your statement is pessimistic. Every silver lining has its doubters, nay sayers

Comment: That was exactly my point, Alaska Man.

Comment: Wonder if we could use the reverse and call it a black lining or something. Unsure which colour would fit best, but black seems most fitting to me

Comment: A bit of a tongue-in-cheek inversion of the phrase that may fit better is "every silver lining has a cloud". (Unfortunately, using "cloud" alone doesn't exactly work as well as "silver lining".)

Comment: @Serlite's version is sometimes used to describe pessimists: "they look for the cloud around/on/attached to every silver lining." I especially like this choice for the OP's example, though, as it's weather-related. *Gregory enjoyed the balmy February day, but couldn't help suspecting that it was but a thin silver lining in the black cloud bank of catastrophic and irreversible climate change obscuring the horizon.*

Answer (score 26):

You could say that the good weather was **cold comfort** to Gregory:

> quite limited sympathy, consolation, or encouragement ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold%20comfort))
>
> *The good news about the economy is cold comfort to people who have lost their jobs.*

Comment: "Gregory took cold comfort in the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change." - makes perfect sense to me

Comment: close, but not quite. I had the exact same feeling as the fictitious Gregory the other day: "ooh lovely weather, sunshine, feel happy....... but oh bugger, it's probably caused by climate change"

Comment: This is a good suggestion!

Comment: I disagree — cold comfort is usually no comfort at all. Just look at Merriam-Webster's example.

Comment: I wouldn't use this in the exact phrase given: the word 'balmy' might not be fully understood by all readers, and the phrase "Gregory took cold comfort in the balmy weather" could be interpreted as cold-heat rather than as a descriptor of the comfort. Whilst strictly correct, kindness and clarity to readers of all abilities should be considered. (However, if the sentence was not about the weather, this would be a cool (haha, pun intended) way of saying it, as per your example from Merriam-Webster).

Comment: +1 this seems like the best option that is not "bittersweet". Actually captures the idea of something good with a little bad.

Answer (score 25):

Not a word but an idiom:

***[a blessing in disguise](http://Losing%20that%20job%20was%20a%20blessing%20in%20disguise%20really.)***:

> something that seems bad or unlucky at first, but results in something good happening later:
>
> - *Losing that job was a blessing in disguise really.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: This fits the title of the question but not the example. "Gregory felt the balmy February day was a blessing in disguise, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change." doesn't make sense

Comment: This would fit if the new job was better than the old job.

Comment: Perhaps inverting a "blessing in disguise" to a "curse in disguise" would work better.  
"Gregory felt the balmy February day was a curse in disguise, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change."  
It feels as if it should work.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know that there's a single term with both a verb and adjective form that will fit. However, the common phrases [***mixed feelings***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mixed-feelings) (to feel "both pleased and not pleased about [something] at the same time", *Cambridge Dictionary*) and [***guilty pleasure***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guilty%20pleasure) ("something pleasurable that induces a usually minor feeling of guilt", Merriam-Webster) might cover your bases.

> Gregory **had mixed feelings about** the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change.
>
> Gregory **took a certain guilty pleasure in** the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change."

Answer (score 4):

My first reaction was something involving the conception of resignation. Example (which certainly doesn't feel 100% right): "Given his concerns about climate change, Gregory felt resignedly glad about the balmy weather." Most dictionary definitions of resignation involve submission or acquiescence; what Gregory is submitting to here is his own happiness, despite his principles. "Reluctant pleasure" could also be along the right lines.

Answer (score 4):

*Gregory **mused it was an ill wind that blows nobody any good,** as he enjoyed the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change.*

> **it's an ill wind (that blows nobody any good)**
>   saying:
>   *said to show that even a very bad situation must have some good results*
>   —  [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-s-an-ill-wind-that-blows-nobody-any-good)

Quoting [www.phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/ill-wind.html) :

> [...]
>   This is first recorded in John Heywood's
>   *A dialogue conteinyng the nomber in effect of all the prouerbes in the Englishe tongue, 1546*:
>   **"An yll wynde that blowth no man to good, men say."**
>   [...]

Comment: Like that time I maxed out my credit card betting on Trump to win the election?  (Sadly this didn't happen)

Comment: @MaxWilliams so I guess he is really an ill wind.

Answer (score 2):

" *Gregory felt **solace** about the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible"

This one isn't an idiom like the previously mentioned examples:

**Silver Lining**

**Light at The End of the Tunnel**

**Cold Comfort**

Solace is a single-use word in the English language that refers exactly to the scenario which you are describing.

From Google:

**Solace** (noun)

1)
comfort or consolation in a time of great distress or sadness.

"she sought solace in her religion"

Comment: If it fits the situation exactly, use it in the example sentence. It doesn't seem to fit at all, to me. Seems backwards actually, like silver lining. Should be finding some sadness in something that is otherwise happy.

Answer (score 1):

You've indicated that "bittersweet" is not *precisely* right, and maybe you're correct, but it's still better than any other option that's been presented.

Although Gregory may not have felt bittersweet immediately, when he was just enjoying the balmy day, he certainly does after thinking about climate change.

Some definitions for "bittersweet":

**[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bittersweet)**

> both pleasant and painful or regretful

[**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bittersweet)

> when something is good but there is a bad part about it

[**Merriam-Webster**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet)

> being at once bitter and sweet; especially :  pleasant but including or marked by elements of suffering or regret

[**Oxford Dictionaries**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bittersweet)

> Arousing pleasure tinged with sadness or pain.

You indicated in your reservations concerning the word that "bittersweet" indicates ambivalence, but I don't see that in any definition, and wouldn't agree based on my knowledge of the word.

Furthermore, you're specifically looking for something that indicates goodness or happiness, but with a tinge of sadness, as opposed to "silver lining", which indicates the opposite. From several of these definitions, you can see that "bittersweet" fits this description perfectly.

Comment: While *bittersweet* well-expresses the ultimate sentiment, it lacks the transformational flavor of *tarnished pleasure*. This is why you had to add the "although" clause. *Tarnished pleasure* is quite evocative: Gregory is happy initially, but then the doubts boil up.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario can be described as ***conflicted***:

> *adj*
>   unable to decide between opposing feelings or views
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conflicted)</sub>

In your sample:

> Gregory felt **conflicted** **about** the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change.

Comment: +1 Reminds me of the joke about watching your mother-in-law driving over a cliff in your new Mercedes....

Answer (score 0):

How about **Appease**
*verb (used with object), appeased, appeasing.*

1. to bring to a state of peace, quiet, ease, calm, or contentment; pacify; soothe:
   to appease an angry king.
2. to satisfy, allay, or relieve; assuage:
   The fruit appeased his hunger

Comment: Can you show how this fits in the example sentence?

Comment: The point of appease is that it not that it brings peace, so much as that it makes anger go away. And of course, there is the negative implications that come from appeasement.

Answer (score 0):

> "Gregory [verb-ed | felt adjective about] the balmy February day, suspecting it was yet another consequence of catastrophic and irreversible climate change."

For this particular case the following come to mind:

> *Gregory **savored** with a sense of **unease** the balmy February day, suspecting that...* /
>   *Gregory **savored uneasily** the balmy February day, suspecting that...*

The verb ***temper*** could also be used with a noun, probably with wider applicability than the *savor/unease* examples.

> *Gregory's **enjoyment** of the balmy February day was **tempered** by a suspicion that...*

Answer (score -1):

**Fortunate** (adjective)

> receiving good from uncertain or unexpected sources ([Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fortunate))
>
> Gregory was fortunate to have the balmy weather,...

*Fortune* doesn't have a verb form in the same sense.

Answer (score -2):

You might look at the concept of deep comedy outlined by Peter Leithart. While his usage of it is for Trinitarian theology, I think it explains this dynamic well. Not really a word, though, and would need some explanation.

Deep comedy is the idea that mankind went from garden, to garden lost, and for God's elect will ultimately get to garden city (heaven) through redemption. It acknowledges the fall, but views it through a lens of fortune due to the greater glory of redemption (think of sun shining brighter after a storm). Another way the idea is often put is "fortunate fall."

Again, it is steeped in theology so may not work for your use, but the concept is rich at least.

Comment: you haven't explained what this has to do with feeling happy at a sunny day, followed by feeling sad that it is probably caused by climate change. In the mythological example that you give, humanity is supposed to feel sad at being cast out of the Garden, but then happy that it gave rise to the Incarnation. However, in the weather/climate change example, it is happiness followed by sadness.

Answer (score -2):

Again a phrase rather than a single word, but how about:

> George saw the **light at the end of the tunnel.**

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel) defines it as the "hope of success, happiness, or help after a long period of difficulty".

Comment: This is the opposite of what is required.